# How to get multiple controls to fire same event/command in Silverlight / XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, triggers, mvvm-light

I am using Mvvm-Light Commands to route events from my Views to my ViewModels. Works great.

But I think I can be more elegant. This is actually probably just a standard XAML question:

I want to change this (10 buttons all with `Click="keypadButton_Click"` for their event handler):

```
<Button  Name="button1" Content="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="keypadButton_Click" />
<Button  Name="button2" Content="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
<Button  Name="button3" Content="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
<Button  Name="button4" Content="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
<Button  Name="button5" Content="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
<Button  Name="button6" Content="6" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
<Button  Name="button7" Content="7" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
<Button  Name="button8" Content="8" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
<Button  Name="button9" Content="9" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
<Button  Name="button0" Content="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Click="keypadButton_Click"/>
```

To 10 of these:

```
<Button  x:Name="button1" Content="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <Command:EventToCommand 
               Command="{Binding KeyPadButtonCommand}"
               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=button1, Path=Content }"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

But I don't want that much XAML. I would think there would be a way to "macroize" the Trigger so it would look something like this:

```
<Button  Name="button1" Content="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
         Click="{Binding _SendTheEventHere_}" />
```

Where `"{Binding _SendTheEventHere_}"` should be replaced with some magic incantation that I am clueless about, but I know some wizard here on stackoverflow knows :-).

Make sense?

Comment: I don't understand WNY you want to do this. What does you binding a click event handler give you that you can't do with this hard coded. I could see that using a command could help with your separation between xaml and code behind but not what binding the eventhandler helps you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can use RelayCommand in MVVM Light Toolkit [here is a sample code](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/26/using-relaycommands-in-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx)

Generally RelayCommand are implementation of ICommand interface that you can use

Comment: Appreciate you commenting, but if you don't understand the question how can you try to answer it?  I am looking for the XAML syntax to "macroize" (simplify) the XAML in the 2nd text snippet so ti looks more like the 3rd.

Comment: yes, so you can write the 2nd text snippet using RelayCommand (RelayCommand). I'm trying to help and your question isn't clear for me at least. Number of answer indicate that for others too

Comment: Sorry if I sounded snippy. It would be really helpful if you could provide your answer in the answer with some sample code. I learn best by seeing actual code that illustrates something. I've never used  RelayCommand so i'm not sure how it would apply in this case. Thanks again.

Comment: In the link (I gave you) you have good explanation of it (with code samples)

Comment: Raf, I did not see your link originally. Stackoverflow makes the link text too similar to the answer text. My bad. It turns out that link was helpful!  Thank you!  However I can't actually get it to work. See my comment to Paul's answer above.

Comment: Raf, I'd like to vote up this answer but SO won't let me unless you edit it some first (it won't let you chaange a vote after 8 hours).

Comment: Ok, thank you for good words. I will try to answer in Paul answer

Answer (score 0):

I have just run a test using the following XAML and it seems to work successfully :-

Your Button XAML :-

```
<Button Name="MyConfirmButton" 
        Content="Confirm" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
        i:Interaction.Triggers="{StaticResource PerformConfirm}">
</Button>
```

Your Resource XAML :-

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <i:EventTrigger x:Key="PerformConfirm" EventName="Click">
      <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=PerformConfirm}" />
   </i:EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I still don't see the point against using Command attribute. Then you can simply write: <Button Command="{Binding MyOwnCommand}"/>

Comment: Hi, Is the Command property only available in SL4? If so, this will not work for SL3.

Comment: Yes, its available for SL4, but for example MVVM Light Toolkit has it's own implementation: ButtonBaseExtensions.Command, so you can use it in SL3 too. Then it would be: <Button cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding MyOwnCommand}" />

Comment: Thank you Raf for pointing that out. It has made my XAML much cleaner.

Comment: This looks great.  However, I'm getting "The attachable property 'Command' was not found in type 'ButtonBaseExtensions'.  I'm using the WP7 version of Mvvm-Light, but that shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: Have you added this namespace: xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP7"?

If not you have to do it and then in the button you have to write:
cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding MyCommand}"

Comment: I had xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP7".  Note the ".Extras".  I added "xmlns:cmdxtra="... MvvmLight"" without the Extras and it now works, but why do I have to define both namespaces. Seems clumsy!

Comment: I think you don't need GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP7 (of course if you don't use it). The GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP7 namespace is needed for access to ButtonBaseExtensions.Command type. I'm glad that your code works now

Comment: But cmd:EventToCommand is in Extras.WP7, so both are needed. Im gonna create a new ? for this topic. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh, if you need EventToCommand then you need Extra.WP7. Typically you need to add namespace to types that you're going to use. When you create classes you can put them in many assemblies and then you need to reference them (every namespace in xaml is referencing to one assembly).